# i got StopIteration error , how to solve this error

Tags: python, image, classification, image-preprocessing, stopiteration

i am storing the names of each image in the filename array and labels associated with that image in labels array. so i wrote this code

```
import numpy as np

subdirs, dirs, files = os.walk('/content/all_images').__next__()
m = len(files)
print(m)

filenames = []
labels = np.zeros((m, 1))

import os
import shutil

images_dir = '/content/all_images'
filenames_counter = 0
labels_counter = -1

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(train_dir):
    #print(files)
    for file in files:
        filenames.append(file)
        labels[filenames_counter, 0] = labels_counter
        filenames_counter = filenames_counter + 1
    labels_counter = labels_counter+1
    
print(len(filenames))
print(labels.shape)
```

but i got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-4f63fd378da3>", line 3, in <module>
    subdirs, dirs, files = os.walk('/content/all_images').__next__()

StopIteration
```

how to solve this error ?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: Looks like `os.walk('/content/all_images')` returned an empty iterator

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-4f63fd378da3>", line 3, in <module>
    subdirs, dirs, files = os.walk('/content/all_images').__next__()

StopIteration